# target="_blank" on IE9 doesn't open a new tab or window

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm trying to specify link behaviour by setting the target to _blank if the link is external and _self if link is internal. It works in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox just fine but when the site is tested on IE9, the external links are opened as if they had a _self target.

Inspecting the HTML elements, I get this which is what I expected to see.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/" target="_blank">External Link
            <i class="icon icon-point-right-circled"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://test.mysite.com/uk/en/Documents/Test%20document.pdf" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon icon-download-circled"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried adding a style attribute to the  tag:

```
<a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/" target="_blank" @(isInternal ? @Html.Raw(style=\"target-new: window\"") : @Html.Raw(string.Empty))>
    <i class="icon icon-download-circled"></i>
</a>
```

That didn't work.

Any ideas what I might have been missing?

Regards,
Tim

Comment: Maybe there is custom js event on click at `a` element.

Comment: There's an option for this in "Internet Options", user can choose how "popups" are treated.